# Using a Bool in a Swift condition statement gives error: "initialization of variable newCard was never used"

Tags: ios, swift, boolean

Essentially what I want to do is have the bool variable `newCard` be set to true when `playButton` runs, that way when `firstCardPressed` runs, it will only set the image if its True, and then reset it back to false.

The issue is that I'm getting an error stating

> initialization of variable newCard was never used

But I can't seem to figure out how to initialize it correctly.

```
  @IBAction func playButton(sender: UIButton) {    
    // Randomize the face up stack
    let firstRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(52))
    let firstCardString:String = self.deckArray[firstRandomNumber]
    self.faceUpStack.image = UIImage(named: firstCardString)
    var newCard = true    
  }

  @IBAction func firstCardPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let cardKept = self.faceUpStack.image
    if newCard == true {
      self.firstCard.image = cardKept
      newCard = false
    }
  }
```

Comment: Declare newcard outside your ibaction

Comment: Comparing a bool == true it is redundant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
  var newCard = false
 @IBAction func playButton(sender: UIButton) {    
    // Randomize the face up stack
    let firstRandomNumber:Int = Int(arc4random_uniform(52))
    let firstCardString:String = self.deckArray[firstRandomNumber]
    self.faceUpStack.image = UIImage(named: firstCardString)
    newCard = true    
  }

  @IBAction func firstCardPressed(sender: UIButton) {
    let cardKept = self.faceUpStack.image
    if newCard {
      self.firstCard.image = cardKept
      newCard = false
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

newCard in your playButtonFunc is a local variable. It appears when the func starts, and it disappears without a track when the func finishes. "var newCard = true" as the very last statement in your func is pointless, as the compiler tells you, because the local variable newCard disappears an instance later.

You probably want it to be an instance variable in your class. There's a good chance that it already is, because otherwise firstCardPressed wouldn't compile.